# Get diesel or gasoline/petrol filled

Tags: word-usage

When the amount of diesel or petrol/gasoline is low.,  what will be a natural way to describe "filling the tank up"?

> I have to get diesel/gasoline filled.

Or should it be:

> I have to get the tank filled.

Comment: 1. Doesn't work (should be *I need to fill up with diesel...*) and 2. sounds as though it's a major operation and you're not really involved. I suggest *I need (to get) diesel*, *I need to (stop and) fill up*.

Comment: And @Minty,  when you're calling someone up who's driving to "get diesel",  what will be a natural way to say that?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean there. If it's the guy who's gone for diesel speaking he might say *I'm just on my way to get diesel / to fill up*.

Comment: No a person is driving.  So another person calls up and says "you need to fill up or the car will go dead".   So what will be a natural way to describe that? @Minty

Comment: And you are asking what the driver would say? If it was me I'd go with *shut up Mum there's a gauge right here in front of me*. If I was calling my gf because I thought she might not notice and let it conk out, then assuming I didn't want to be sarcastic I might say *I left the car nearly empty so check you've got enough petrol*.

Comment: And @Minty can "fill up" be used on phone as well?

Comment: And @Minty what do you think about: "You need to fill up" Or "You need to fill the tank up. "

Answer (score 0):

Really, the standard way in the US is to simply say "I need to get gas". The context of filling the car's gas tank is just assumed. If you're in New Jersey or some place that still has full service you say to the attendant "fill her up (with regular/premium)".